# The Big O Notation for reading a textfile with 5-20 words

Tags: algorithm, big-o

i have a algorithm that opens a textfile, reads between 5 and 20 words, store them into an array and closes the textfile again.

Has this algorithm a Big O Natation (1) or (n)?

Comment: How are these 5 to 20 words chosen?

Comment: they are chosen more or less by an admin, so they won't increase and won't go above the limit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to go against common opinion here and say it's `O(n)` where `n` is the average word length. Clearly if the length of those 20 words doubles, so does the amount of work you need to do to read them.

If the maximum length of the words is also constant however, it will be `O(1)`.

Comment: I'm with you on that.  Just reading them and throwing them away is `O(n)`.

Comment: It's also O(n) where n is the size of the input data (in the file), and that's a more conventional definition of `n` than anything involving an average. Not that it makes any difference in this case, where of course the data size is bounded below by 5*average, and above by 20*average, so the two are complexity-equivalent anyway.

Comment: the words a "real" /"common" words, like products or places or month. the length of the words is not greater than (i guess) 20 letters ( if i get you right) in my special case

Comment: @Tyzak: if there is no quantity in your problem that can increase without bound, then big-O analysis is not really appropriate. But as far as the analysis goes, bounded operations of course are O(1).

Answer (score 4):

It's O(1) unless you tell us what `n` is supposed to be.

Comment: i thought for example by a searching algorithm, to go trough an array has an O(n) [as far as I learned]. n would be a variable. (because the numer is not fix, but the number is limeted by 5-20 words]

Comment: In that case, `n` is probably the number of elements in the array. It is not mentioned explicitly, but pretty obvious. In your case, it is not so obvious, what `n` should be. The size of the file? The number of words that the algorithm should read? Or (as sepp2k suggested) the average word length?

Answer (score 3):

If every single time the algorithm is run, it reads no more than 20 words, then it is O(1), as the time that it takes to run the algorithm does not get longer as the number of words in the text file increases.

Answer (score 1):

O(1) it will always use a bounded number of operations.